# Links and keyboard focus

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3

This question is about keyboard focus for various kinds of links.

**Link inside div** - a simple link like below can be accessed by keyboard tabindex, but there's a gap between the div and the link so the mouse can hover over the `div` without setting off the link's `:hover` event.

```
<div class="greenButton">
  <%= link_to "Back", :back %>
</div>
```

**Div inside link** - the code below keeps `:hover` events together (and in general the styled link behaves how I would expect) but the keyboard doesn't get to it through tabindex.

```
<%= link_to :back do %>
  <div class="greenButton">Back</div>
<% end %>
```

How can I get both the better formatting of the bottom situation with a tabindex?

**Note:** the manual `tabindex` declaration is not a good option because this is code that will be used for multiple pages where there are different numbers of elements. Is there a Rails-y way to do this?

Comment: Which browsers did you try? You have the same problem in all browsers?

Comment: @mischa - I ran across the problem in Chrome. I haven't tested it elsewhere as yet.

Comment: Thanks. You accepted my answer. Does that mean your problem is solved? If you still need help styling your link without using divs, please show us your CSS.

Comment: @mischa - yes, and thank you! I found that consolidating the two elements into one `link_to` with the class was the way to go, as you and a few others mentioned. The code you pasted also reminded me of the invalidity of putting a `<div>` inside the `<a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other
>   block-level elements. Generally, inline elements may contain only data
>   and other inline elements. Inherent in this structural distinction is
>   the idea that block elements create "larger" structures than inline
>   elements.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#block-inline)

In other words: you shouldn't put a block element like `div` inside an inline element like `a`. I recommend losing the `div` and just style the `a` element:

```
<%= link_to "Back", :back, :class => 'greenButton' %>
```

If this isn't feasible, you could try replacing the `div` with a `span` and see if the tabindex gets picked up.

Answer (score 1):

Lose the `<div>`, it doesn't serve any good purpose there. (Most single-child elements don't)

Use a class on your link

```
<%= link_to "Back", :back, :class => 'greenButton' %>
```

and make that a block element in your CSS

```
a.greenButton {
  display: block;
  background-color: #9F6;
  …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "Back", :back, :class => 'greenButton', :style => 'display: block;' %>
```

Comment: Inline styles when you have a class declaration? Not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.1):

> Elements that may receive focus should be navigated by user agents
>   according to the following rules:
>
> - Those elements that support the tabindex attribute and assign a
>     positive value to it are navigated first. Navigation proceeds from the
>     element with the lowest tabindex value to the element with the highest
>     value. Values need not be sequential nor must they begin with any
>     particular value. Elements that have identical tabindex values should
>     be navigated in the order they appear in the character stream.
> - Those elements that do not support the tabindex attribute or
>     support it and assign it a value of "0" are navigated next. These
>     elements are navigated in the order they appear in the character
>     stream.
> - Elements that are disabled do not participate in the tabbing
>     order.

So perhaps disable the `tabindex` assignments and let the browser use the second method?